# Text changes to an image on hover

Tags: html, css

I am trying to change a text to an image on hover, using CSS iv'e tried some stuff so far but none helped me and i tried googling it but nothing very helpful.

Also the picture that i have is very big it's a screenshot.

I am trying to make something like this from this guy's portfolio where he showcases his projects.

http://pierre.io/#

this is my HTML :

```
<div class="jumbotron projectsJumbotron2">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-sm-6">
                <h2>Discover</h2>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS :

```
.projectsJumbotron2{
    background:transparent;
    padding-top: 100px;
}
.projectsJumbotron2 .container .row .col-sm-6 h2{
    font-family: lobster;
    padding-left: 100px;
    font-size: 50px;
}
```

Basically he has when you hover over the logo it transitions into a screenshot of his project. but i want when i hover over my H2 for it to transition into a screenshot.

Comment: Please add your CSS and any JavaScript you've written.

Comment: The CSS that i added is just to customize my h2 and the position of it. il add it tho.

Comment: It is expected that you at least attempt to code this for yourself. Stack Overflow is not a code writing service. I would suggest that you do some additional research, either via Google or by searching SO, make an attempt and. if you still have trouble, come back with **your code** and explain what you have tried and why it did not work.

Comment: If that's all you have, you're essentially asking for the code to be written for you.

That being said I can point you in the right direction.

http://codepen.io/knolaust/pen/bNvZRQ

Comment: Guys. I've wrote up that i did research for it, and i tried some stuff that didn't work so i deleted my work. and put the raw thing so it won't get confusing. and i repeat i wrote that i did research if you can't read that it's not my fault.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will work:

```
<style type="text/css">
.pic {
   position: absolute;
   opacity: 0;
   transition: all 0.5s ease;
}
.pic:hover {opacity: 1;}
</style>
<div class="jumbotron projectsJumbotron2">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-sm-6">
                <img class="pic" src="img/pic.jpg" />
                <h2>Discover</h2>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Yeah it works exactly what i was searching for. i was going in the wrong ways with this. i tried putting the h2 to display block then none on hover and it was all messy and didn't work at all, i understand now how to make it happen thanks a lot.